# How can I get a div to fill the entire page's width?

Tags: css, html

I want to make a color blocked webpage, but when using a DIV with a background, there are whitespace between the edge of the screen!

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/espevoir/mBgyM/

```
<div class="one">hi</div>
<div class="two">hi</div>
.one {
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
background-color: Navy;
}

.two {
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
background: Red;
}
```

Help? :3

Thanks it advance!

Comment: Your HTML is broken. Fix it first and then try to see what CSS issues you have.

Comment: What does color blocked mean? Your fiddle doesn't correspond with the markup you have supplied. Please clarify what you are after.

Comment: Um somehow I linked to the wrong fiddle, sorry about that. Color blocking is a popular style used in web design, fashion, art etc. updating link now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your body margin to 0;

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
position:fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

style for the div. try this. normally this is used to make popup.